# DB2 SELECT FOR UPDATE with INNER JOIN

Tags: select, db2, sql-update, deadlock

I am trying to work out a DB2 Issue. I make an update based on a previous Select and occasionally encounter Deadlocks when two transactions run the select in parallel and none of them is able to update afterwards.

So I am trying to solve this using Select For Update, but apparently, Select For Update does not work with inner join, is that correct? And is there a way around it?

Here's my Select Statement

```
SELECT s.ID FROM DATA.TABLE_A s 
    INNER JOIN DATA.TABLE_B n ON s.ID = n.ID 
    WHERE n.N_ID = ? 
        AND n.N_TYPE = ? 
        AND n.PN_ID = ? 
        AND n.PN_TYPE = ? 
        AND n.RN_ID = ?  
        AND s.P_ID = ? 
        AND s.C_ID = ?
FOR UPDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only updating one table, you could try using a subselect instead of a join. Say, if you target `TABLE_A` for update, this might work:

```
SELECT s.ID FROM DATA.TABLE_A s 
WHERE s.ID IN (
  SELECT n.ID
  FROM DATA.TABLE_B n   
    WHERE n.N_ID = ? 
        AND n.N_TYPE = ? 
        AND n.PN_ID = ? 
        AND n.PN_TYPE = ? 
        AND n.RN_ID = ? 
) 
AND s.P_ID = ? 
AND s.C_ID = ?
FOR UPDATE
```

Comment: This worked, but I still get the Deadlocks. Can a SELECT FOR UPDATE access a row with U-Lock? Otherwise I would need an exclusive lock, right?

Comment: It's impossible to answer generally, because lock modes depend on the DB2 version and platform, the chosen access plan, and transaction isolation level -- all of which are missing from the question. In most cases deadlocks indicate flawed or inappropriate application logic and as such they rarely can be fixed by tweaking SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following, means specify `WITH RS` (Read Stability) in your select statement:

```
SELECT ....(
............
) FOR UPDATE WITH RS USE AND KEEP UPDATE LOCKS
```

Comment: I appended this at the end of @mustaccio 's suggestion. The query works now, but when executing the select --> update sequence 100 times at once I still get Deadlocks. Do I actually need exclusive locks here?